# C# same disposable resource getting wrapped in multiple using block

Tags: c#, using

Just was going through some code for refactoring and puzzled to see something similar to the following

```
public class FooDisposable : IDisposable { }

using (var foo = new FooDisposable())
{
    EagerToDisposeMethod(foo);
    //Do something else with foo
}

void EagerToDisposeMethod(FooDisposable fooDisposable)
{
    using (fooDisposable)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Wondering at what point it will be ready for disposal?

Also why can't this be a compiler warning atleast, "trying to dispose something that was not created in the current scope"?

In c#, can using block be aware of ambient usings on the same resource (like TransactionScope, etc)?

Comment: It's *frequently* correct to dispose of something not created in the current scope, even though in this particular case that object is still being used elsewhere.  It's not *always* wrong (in fact, it's very often not) so it doesn't make sense as a warning.

Comment: "Wondering at what point it will be ready for disposal?" `fooDisposable.Dispose()` will be called every single time the control flow exists a `using` block, so it will be called twice in your example.

Comment: It will be disposed in `EagerToDisposeMethod` and potentially cause issues when used after that.  As for the compiler not warning you, it's a matter of the complexity of it finding this particular issue.  There are however static code checkers that might catch this or that you could write a custom rule if they don't.

Comment: @Servy, could you give an example scenario (when following best practices) to dispose something that's getting passed in as an argument?

Comment: It depends on ownership of the object. As a general purpose method, I'd say the above code is a bug, but if the `EagerToDisposeMethod` method actually takes ownership of the object passed to it, then it is ok. In that case, however, I would think there is a bug in the outer code though. It is rare to purposely write the code as in the question, where you *know* two distinct places where an object will *always* be disposed.

Comment: @NasmiSabeer It's common enough for an object to take ownership of a disposable resources passed to it, where the caller relinquishes ownership and stops using it.  Often in such situations the disposable resource being passed in gets "consumed" and is no longer usable, such as a stream of data of some kind.